# Create CSV with single column header in Java

Tags: java, csv, header

How can I create CSV file in Java and set the header data in single columns instead of comma separated? For example:

Column A = Header1

Column B= Header2

Then write data below of each header:

Header1  Header2

Text1     Text2

Any example please?
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CSV` stand for `Comma Seperated value` and you want a `CSV` without a comma seperator?

Comment: You should explain where you have problems with. Best it to show a small piece of code which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @UmaKanth Although the acronym says *comma*, its very common to have other delimiters for a csv file like *caret(^)* or simply a *space or tab*. Most of the csv file parsers are capable of identifying these delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Check my answer, I gave an option to change the `seperator`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to write CSV:

```
CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //many options here. Check the documentation

settings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|'); 

CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path/to/output.csv")), settings);

writer.writeHeaders("Header A", "Header B");

//write rows individually
writer.writeRow("string 1", "string 2"); 
writer.writeRow(234, new BigDecimal(111)); 

//or write a list of rows in bulk
List<Object[]> yourRows = yourMethodToBuildRowsWithData();

writer.writeRowsAndClose(yourRows);
```

It seems you could use TSV instead of CSV to produce easier to visualise columns, separated by tab. In this case just replace the *CsvWriterSettings* and *CsvWriter* by *TsvWriterSettings* and *TsvWriter*

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the simple solution how to create CSV file and store the headers and values in separated columns. The example we need to have is:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
Value1  Value2
```

I didn’t use any library, using Java’s FileWriter I do the following. Change the comma delimiter from (,) to (;) as in example below.

private static final String **COMMA_DELIMITER = ";";**

Then define columns name and the rest example code.

```
private static final String FILE_HEADER = " **ColumnA; ColumnB**";
FileWriter fileWriter = null;
fileWriter = new FileWriter("your_csv_file.csv");
// Write the CSV file header
fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());
// Add a new line separator after the header
fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
fileWriter.append(“Value1”);                
fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
fileWriter.append(“Value2”);
fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

Please note that you have to write the code correctly with try-catch and finally blocks.